# pythonでのウェブスクレイピングにエラーが出るので、原因を特定していただきたいです。

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

## 質問

プログラミング学習本である、コーリー・アルソフ著「独学プログラマー」（2018発行。手元にあるのは2021年発行の刊）のP.243に記載されているウェブスクレイパーのコードを実行するも、エラーが出て原因が特定できません。
この本のサイトにて補足が公開されていたため、そちらも試しましたがうまくいきません。

https://shop.nikkeibp.co.jp/front/commodity/0000/C92270/

pythonを学習している先輩に相談したところ、pythonのバージョンとモジュールの組み合わせが悪いのではないか、ssh通信の認証を回避する必要があるのかも、といった仮説を頂きましたが、自分自身もまだ学習をはじめたてでもあり、うまく理解ができませんでした。
ちなみにpythonは3.10.0です。

下記にコードとエラーを記載したので、原因が特定できる方がいたら教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

## コード

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site

    def scrape(self):
        r = urllib.request.urlopen(self.site)
        html = r.read()
        parser = "html.parser"
        sp = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
        print(html)
        for tag in sp.find_all("a"):
            url = tag.get("href")
            print(url)
            if url is None:
                continue
            if "topics" in url:
                print("\n" + url)

news = "https://xtrend.nikkei.com/atcl/contents/new/"
Scraper(news).scrape()
```

## エラー

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/taguchimasataka/Desktop/p241のコピー.py", line 26, in <module>
    Scraper(news).scrape()
  File "/Users/taguchimasataka/Desktop/p241のコピー.py", line 15, in scrape
    sp = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 228, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 289, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 215, in feed
    parser.feed(markup)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 110, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 178, in goahead
    k = self.parse_html_declaration(i)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/html/parser.py", line 269, in parse_html_declaration
    self.handle_decl(rawdata[i+2:gtpos])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 160, in handle_decl
    self.soup.endData(Doctype)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 365, in endData
    self.object_was_parsed(o)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 370, in object_was_parsed
    previous_element = most_recent_element or self._most_recent_element
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1054, in __getattr__
    return self.find(tag)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1292, in find
    l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1313, in find_all
    return self._find_all(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 528, in _find_all
    strainer = SoupStrainer(name, attrs, text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1610, in __init__
    self.text = self._normalize_search_value(text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1615, in _normalize_search_value
    if (isinstance(value, str) or isinstance(value, collections.Callable) or hasattr(value, 'match')
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'
```

Comment: エラーログの中で `/Users/***/Desktop/` のところに人名らしき文字列が残ってしまっていますが，意図通りでしょうか……（意図通りでなければ適当に置き換える等した方がよさそうです）

Comment: 英語版 Stack Overflow に類似の質問がありました．質問に記載のコードが悪いのではなく，単純に BeautifulSoup がまだ Python 3.10 に対応していないのが原因かもしれません．そういうこともあるので，質問には Python のバージョンだけでなく BeautifulSoup のバージョンも載せておくといいかもしれませんね．
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69515086/

Comment: Windows10, Python 3.10.1, beautifulsoup4 4.10.0 の組み合わせで動作してhtmlとurlは表示されています。その版数で表示されないなら、proxy,firewall,ウイルスチェックソフトや組織内のネットワーク関連設定などが影響しているのかもしれません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラーの直接の原因は、 BeautifulSoup4 が内部で Python 標準ライブラリの `collections.Callable` を参照しているせいです。これは Python 3.10 で削除されました。

現時点の最新版である BeautifulSoup4 4.10.0 では修正済みのようなのでアップデートしてみてください。うまくいかないようなら Python 3.9 以下を使ってください。